# Block path using htaccess or some other way

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am using multi domain hosting and have a domain say `http://demo.com` ,
which resides on a subdomain on some other domain say `http://example.com/demo/public_html`

I want to block access to the

```
http://example.com/demo/public_html

http://example.com/demo/
```

folders, so that can't be accessed from `http://example.com`
and the demo.com can be accessed from `http://demo.com`

*
I tried using .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

in demo folder, the access is blocked but `http://demo.com` also gets blocked.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just block other domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^(www\.)?demo\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```